# Stellar nucleosynthesis

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, stars, fusion

I would like to learn more about fusion in stars. The question I have is whether there exists a graph showing exactly which elements take part in the reactions.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction), I managed to find some data about the initial stages of stellar nucleosynthesis, but I'm intrested in knowing what happens later, i.e. what processes are involved in getting heavier elements than Berylium even up to the supernova.

If this question turns out to be too complex for a short answer, I would like to have some figurative sketch of the most important reactions that take place in the stars, i.e. I would like to focus only on the essential reactions in fusion and not the reactions that happen with $~0.1\%$ probability.

P.S. Any resources that adress this problem will be greatly appreciated. Please don't post answers regarding only the Hydrogen or Helium burning, but try to focus on the global picture.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_nucleosynthesis has a number of reaction listed.

Comment: This paper addresses the problem [(Bethe)](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.55.103)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principle process you are asking about is the [alpha ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_process#:%7E:text=The%20alpha%20process%2C%20also%20known,being%20the%20triple%2Dalpha%20process.). It starts with the triple alpha process

[image: triple alpha process]

During the giant stages of stellar evolution, alpha particles are added to nuclei in shells.

Figures are from my book, [Structures of the Sky](https://www.troubador.co.uk/bookshop/computing-science-education/light-after-dark-i/), which has a chapter on stellar evolution.

[image: burning]

Answer (score 0):

This paper addresses the problem [(Bethe)](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.55.103) as seen in Table 1.

[image]